# context.drawImage() not working with images loaded with promise

Tags: javascript, promise, html5-canvas

So, I have to load some images and I'm using a promise to do that, however it doesn't seem to work, since the images are not drawn onto the canvas(I'm only expecting to see the last image, since the coordinates are the same, but still).
But if I use the good ol' onload event, everything works.

Here's the code, that loads the images:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");

    var blockNames=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(function(e){
        return "assets/block"+e+".png";
    }); //create an array with paths here

    Promise.all(blockNames.map(function(e){
        return res.loadImage(e);
    })).then(function(result){ //when every promise is fulfilled, draw the current image onto the canvas
        result.map(function(e){
            var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(e, 20, 20);
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("error: "+err);
    });
});
```

And here's the res.loadImage(...) function(I'm using browserify):

```
var loadImage=function(path){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=resolve.call(null, img);
        img.onerror=reject.call(null, img);
        img.src=path;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolve function is called immediately, wrap it in a function :

```
img.onload = function() {
    resolve.call(null, img);
};

img.onerror = function() {
    reject.call(null, img);
};
```